# QT - empty QLineEdits not being passed as NULL when writing to SQL database

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt

I'm relatively new to QT and C++ and am trying to make a basic front-end for a database.

I've hit a snag where `QlineEdits` that are left empty or blank write empty data into the database. By that I mean if I `select * where 'column'is NULL`, I get no results. But If I `select * where 'column' = ''` then I will get all `empty` rows.

Is there any way to change this behavior? Or have them written in as NULL? I'm worried it will cause havoc too for fields where I want the database to store `QlineEdit` data as integers but it will attempt to write in white space.
I could pre-set `QlineEdits` to `0` i.e.

`ui->txt_NAF->setText();`

but this will not eliminate human error.

Anyone have a solution for this problem?

Snippet of QT code used to insert into database (SQL server) below;

```
void log::on_pushButton_clicked()  /* this is my save button */
{
MainWindow conn;
QString BANK_MNTH, BUSN_MNGR, CUST_FRST_NAME, CUST_LAST_NAME, DEAL_NUMB ,COST;

        BANK_MNTH=ui->txt_BANK_MNTH->text();
        BUSN_MNGR=ui->txt_BUSN_MNGR->text();         
        CUST_FRST_NAME=ui->txt_CUST_FRST_NAME->text();
        CUST_LAST_NAME=ui->txt_CUST_LAST_NAME->text();            
        DEAL_NUMB=ui->txt_DEAL_NUMB->text();           
        COST=ui->txt_NAF->text();            

if(!conn.connOpen()){
    qDebug()<<"Failed to open database";
    return;
}
conn.connOpen();
QSqlQuery qry;

qry.prepare("insert into LOG (BANK_MNTH, BUSN_MNGR, CUST_FRST_NAME, CUST_LAST_NAME, DEAL_NUMB ,COST) values ('"+BANK_MNTH    +"','"+BUSN_MNGR+"','"+CUST_FRST_NAME+"','"+CUST_LAST_NAME+"','"+DEAL_NUMB+"','"+COST+"')");

if(qry.exec( ))
{
QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Save"),tr("Record Saved"));

QSqlQueryModel * modal=new QSqlQueryModel();

QSqlQuery* qry2=new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);

qry2->prepare("select DEAL_NUMB, BUSN_MNGR, CUST_FRST_NAME, CUST_LAST_NAME, COST from LOG order by DEAL_NUMB DESC");

qry2->exec();
modal->setQuery(*qry2);
ui->tableView->setModel(modal);
ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents(); 
ui->tableView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
conn.connClose();
foreach(QLineEdit *log, this->findChildren<QLineEdit*>()) {
    log->clear();

}
}
else
{
  QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error"),qry.lastError().text());
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write them as NULL....

Use place holders for inserting values and pass a null `QVariant` using below function to add NULL.

```
void QSqlQuery::bindValue(const QString &placeholder, const QVariant &val, QSql::ParamType paramType = QSql::In)
```

Your code may look like this ... (Did it for few variables for your idea...)

Write a prepare statement for `insert` using place holders.

```
query.prepare("INSERT INTO LOG (BANK_MNTH, BUSN_MNGR, CUST_FRST_NAME) "
                  "VALUES (:BankMonth, :BusManager, :CustFirstName)");
```

Now you have BankMonth,BusManager and CustFirstName as place holders of your `insert` statement.

Now bind the values to place holders as shown below.

Use ternary operator or what ever is convenient to you.
Check if the text is empty, if so pass `QVariant(QVariant::String)` for NULL else pass the text.

```
//Some rough code (Not compiled and tested)

BANK_MNTH=ui->txt_BANK_MNTH->text();
BUSN_MNGR=ui->txt_BUSN_MNGR->text();         
CUST_FRST_NAME=ui->txt_CUST_FRST_NAME->text();

query.bindValue(":BankMonth", BANK_MNTH.trimmed().isEmpty() ? QVariant(QVariant::String): BANK_MNTH);
query.bindValue(":BusManager", BUSN_MNGR.trimmed().isEmpty() ? QVariant(QVariant::String): BUSN_MNGR);
query.bindValue(":CustFirstName", CUST_FRST_NAME.trimmed().isEmpty() ? QVariant(QVariant::String): CUST_FRST_NAME);
```

Refer `bindValue` documentation.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#bindValue

Comment: Thanks so much, that's really helpful! Should I also be passing integers to the database using something like "int integer_value = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();" instead of as text?

Comment: Been trying a few different things but using the above code only NULL's get passed to the database?